# Jquery mobile grid block width set auto

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile with Phonegap. I want to want a gridview in the footer of the page with 3 blocks. It is similar to a chat page. The 1st block includes a button, the second one includes a input field and the third one includes a submit button.

I want to have the 1st and the 3rd block to have fixed width and the 2nd block to fill the remaining of the space. Here is my code -

HTML -

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a attach"><input type="button" value="Hmm"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b text"><input type="text" value="No"></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c send"><input type="button" value="Yes"></div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS -

```
.attach{
width:70px !important;
text-align:center !important;
}


.text{
width: auto !important;
text-align:center !important;
}

.send{
width:100px !important;
text-align:center;
}
```

It is not working as expected. I am quite new at this. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this answer too, and found it!

replace:

`.text{
width: auto !important;
text-align:center !important;
}`

with:

`.text{
width: calc(100% - 170px) !important;
text-align:center !important;
}`

CSS will calculate the width.

A slightly changed example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq9paqLL/)

---

### Update for PhoneGap:

Since you are using it for making mobile apps, it is not possible in the way I stated above. You need JavaScript to overcome the problem that calc() is not recognized in Android apps.

for example:
`$("#text-block").css("width","100%").css("width","-=170px")`
This needs to be executed after the deviceready event is fired. 
Note that the block containing the text input must have the same id as in the JavaScript file.

A working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq9paqLL/1/)